# How to count the number of times an element appears in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to count the the number of times that an element appears in a list.

I found a way to do it but I am looking for a short an efficient way to do it.

Example:

Find the number of times the number `5` appears in the list `l`.

```
l = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Expected Result would be `4`.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python count items in list", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways:

#### 1. Using `list.count` (simplest and best if you only care about one element):

```
print(l.count(5))
```

#### 2. Using `collections.Counter` (also simple and best if you care about all elements):

```
print(Counter(l)[5])
```

#### 3. Using a list comprehension with `len`:

```
print(len([i for i in l if i == 5]))
```

#### 4. Using a generator expression with `sum`:

```
print(sum(i == 5 for i in l))
```

Comment: the `sum` version could be rewritten as `sum(i == 5 for i in l)`.

Comment: I expect the list comprehension and the generator expresion to be less efficient and they are obviouslly more cryptic. Would recommend the `count` version if you only care about one element and the `collections.Counter` version if you care about multiple items.

Answer (score 2):

**Use `list.count`:**

```
>>> l = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> l.count(5)
4
```

**To find if there is any `5` in the list or not:**

```
>>> l = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> bool(l.count(5))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]  # find the number of 5

c = Counter(l)
print(c[5])  # 4
```

this will be more efficient than `l.count(5)` if you want to know the number of occurrences of the other items. (less efficient if you only care about one item).

Answer (score 0):

It simple
just do:
l.index(5);